# I cannot update my app after "google manage my key"

Tags: android, google-play-console

we create a project in android consoles Google manage your app signing key
Then I upload my apk , first release if ok
but when we update the apk , it says different sh1

You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:

SHA1: C5:B7:05:86:FB:C9:72:5D:CC:0C:F6:27:A0:26:E7:8B:59:E6:7E:D9
and the certificate used to sign the APK that you uploaded has fingerprint:
SHA1: BA:87:48:72:2A:3F:F1:2C:03:9B:5C:F1:4E:93:20:91:43:EE:47:73

"C5:B7:05:86:FB:C9:72:5D:CC:0C:F6:27:A0:26:E7:8B:59:E6:7E:D9" we did not generate this

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading the updated application, be sure that you have incremented the android:versionCode and android:versionName attributes in the element of the manifest file. Also, the package name must be the same and the .apk must be signed with the same private key. If the package name and signing certificate do not match those of the existing version, Market will consider it a new application and will not offer it to users as an update.

Comment: all are checked, I think the problem with upload key

Comment: make sure you have used the same Key alias as well

Comment: “google manage my key” is there any steps I should make before release app for singing